# Arduino code won't compile after saving

Tags: c, compilation, arduino

Every time I run the code below without saving, it it will compile. When I do save it, I get the errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-1.0.4\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `setup'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-1.0.4\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `loop'

I have already tried deleting my Arduino folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)`, downloading it and updating the driver.

Other programs seem to run fine. How can I fix it and what's wrong?

```
#define m_pin1 13
#define m_pin2 12
#define sensorPin 0

int val1;
int val2;
int avg;
int threshold;
int flipTimer = 100;

void setup(){
    pinMode(m_pin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(m_pin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Sensor 1 Average:");
}

void loop(){
    moisture_val();
}

int moisture_val(){
    setSensorPolarity(true);
    delay(flipTimer);
    int val1 = analogRead(sensorPin);
    delay(flipTimer);
    setSensorPolarity(false);
    delay(flipTimer);
    int avg = reportLevels(val1,val2);
    int val2 = 1023 - analogRead(sensorPin);
}

void setSensorPolarity(boolean flip){
    if(flip){
        digitalWrite(m_pin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(m_pin2, LOW);
    }
    else{
        digitalWrite(m_pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(m_pin2, HIGH);
    }
}

int reportLevels(int val1,int val2){
    int avg = (val1 + val2) / 2;
    return(avg);
}
```

Comment: I assume you've chosen the right board, programmer, etc.? Seems like a long shot, but the Arduino compiler can give funky messages...

Comment: Yeah I've made sure everything else was right. I even deleted the driver and reinstalled it. I assume there is nothing wrong with the code though?

Comment: Do you some kind of weird name for the file or something?  Because it looks it's not linking to your file.  Or, I should say, when it does the link, it does not find the setup() and loop() functions that seem clearly defined in your file.

Comment: @Aaron - I'm not seeing anything yet. You say the errors are on 11 and 14. Which lines are those?

Comment: Also, what if you load something that works(like blink) and add this code to it?

Comment: @everyone For some reason it works when i save it under a new name

Answer (score 3):

The IDE expects to find the file in a folder with the same name. Have a look at the structure of the files and folders which work as they should. Once the names match the issue should vanish. If not so, switch the IDE to "verbose" for compiling. This will then allow you to find the temporary folder where the actual C source code is processed. You can then have a look at the program that gets actually compiled and linked. This goes a long way in finding out the real issues.

You might also want to look into the details of the [Arduino build process](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess) while you analyze the verbose compiler output.

Answer (score 2):

The arduino has very specific requirements for the names of the sketches you build. If you saved this as "Main" or "main" you need to save it under a different name somewhere else.

Comment: +1 for this , in my project naming the core .ino file with the setup & loop functions inside it and its enclosing folder "main" caused this issue for me. Note that this only happened when building on my Mac (OSX 10.10.5)  built on Windows 8.1 with folder and .ino file enclosed called "main" with no issues

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem :
The INO file name must not be the same with class name.

I have three files:
DB1280.ino DB1280.cpp DB1280.h
The compile error comes out.
So I changed the DB1280.ino name. Such as SimpleDB1280.ino. The error dispeared.

Comment: To be precise, if I understand it correctly, the .ino file must ahve the same name as the folder which contains it, and eventual other library files (.h, .cpp) CANNOT have the same name (regardless of different extension)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Fixed it by removing spacial characters in the projekt name.

Comment: Please provide more details about which special character was removed that fixed it. This answer is too short and is not likely to be that helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

## Simplify the project name

I've changed my project name using *Save as* to `my-project`. That caused the error you posted.

To solve this, **simplify the project name,** exclude special characters such as `-` from the project name.

Answer (score -1):

You must just inselect choice in preference for external editor.
Explication :When it's select your page arduino is in grey and you can write program.
So when you want to transfert from ardublock to arduino your code is not accepted and it's normal because ardublock is not an external editor for arduino.
Unselect, your arduino page begin white and you can write code and transfert code from ardublock. I had the same problem, I use it and it's run..Have fun :)